# find_elements_by_css_selector is not giving me any output , how to handle it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the values of the list. There is a chance i might not get any value but want to continue with rest of the code but its getting failed. How to handle the situation where there is no value in the list present.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10, 0.1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.e_css_project_search)))
projects = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(self.e_css_project_search)
pro_flag = False

print(projects)
```

its going to exception when i don't get any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `length` count of the list. if length >0 it will do print list. else continue.

```
while(True):
  projects=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10, 0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.e_css_project_search)))
  if(len(projects)>0):
   print(projects)
   break
  else:
    continue
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother to wrap this in the while loop to check the length of projects.  If it's an empty list, you'll just have an empty list.

Comment: I have removed WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10, 0.1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.e_css_project_search))) . Didn't applied while loop. working fine now

Answer (score 1):

The exception is not thrown by `find_elements`, which will return an empty list if no element was found, it's thrown by the `WebDriverWait`, which will throw `TimeoutException` if no element was found.

You can either put it in `try except` block or use `implicitly_wait` instead of `WebDriverWait`

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
projects = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(self.e_css_project_search)
pro_flag = False
print(projects)
driver.implicitly_wait(0)
```

This will look for at least one element to appear in the DOM up to 5 seconds.

*It's important to set `implicitly_wait` back to 0, mixing it with `WebDriverWait` can result in unexpected behavior.